# Select active bootstrap carousel item

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html

```
<div id="carousel-2" class="carousel slide">
   <div class="carousel-inner" >
     <div class="item active">
       <img src="img/slide-2.jpg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       <img src="img/slide-3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="features-text">
Pellentesque egestas dignissim accumsan. Vivamus vitae lacinia orci.
</div>
```

I want to change the `features-text` color to different colors, for example when the second item is active, the color should blue. Below is my jQuery codes:

```
if($('#carousel-2 .carousel-inner').find('.item').eq(1).hasClass('active')) {
    $('.features-text').css('color', 'blue');
}
```

It is not working. any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified it a little, but this is working for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/2PWYJ/

```
if($('#carousel-2 .carousel-inner').children('.item').hasClass('active')) {
     $('.features-text').css('color', 'blue');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I want to expand it. for example I want to change the color of features-text to different colors. when 1st item is active, the color should be blue, when 2nd active, the color should be red, ...

Comment: Well... I suppose this could be handled more efficiently, but I did it in this example with a couple if/else if statements. http://jsfiddle.net/2PWYJ/1/ . It could probably be a little better with some clever data-attributes.

Comment: Here's an example of using the data attributes to assign the color using a little less jQuery. You should be able to use this to get done what you need. http://jsfiddle.net/2PWYJ/2/

Comment: I have tested that method before, the color stays the same. The active class is added dynamically to items, so when the active class is removed from one and added to the another, the color should change, but it does not change. It seems that jQuery couldn't updated the color when active class is add / remove dynamically.

Comment: You'd need to fire off that code when the carousel revolves. Try this. `$('#carousel-2').bind('slid', function() {
    if($('#carousel-2 .carousel-inner').children('.item').hasClass('active')) {
    dcolor = $('.active').data('color');
    $('.features-text').css('color', dcolor);
}
});​` using the data-attribute as above.

Comment: sad to say the color stays to same.

Comment: I really have no idea without seeing the code. I'm just throwing out blind suggestions at this point.

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and hooked all this up with Twitter Bootstrap and the code, and it is indeed working. http://jsfiddle.net/2PWYJ/3/

Comment: My code is up on jsfiddle, you can see it there. http://jsfiddle.net/2PWYJ/3/ . It is working just fine. I'm not sure what other help I can provide.

Comment: You did a lot. can you believe me, I have copied and pasted your codes into my template, but it is not working. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Surprisingly, I copy and paste it into a new empty template and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the "slid" event in Bootstrap's carousel like so:

```
$(function() {
    var $carousel = $('#carousel-2'),
        $items = $carousel.find('.item'),
        $text = $('.features-text');

    $carousel.on('slid', function() {
        var index_ = $items.index($items.filter('.active')),
            newColor = 'red';

        switch(index_) {
            case "0":
                newColor = 'blue';
                break;
            case "1":
                newColor = 'red';
                break;
        }
        $text.css('color', newColor);
    });
});
```

didn't try the code above, but you should get the direction :-)

Comment: Thanks for your redponce, It only changes the color to red, it does not change the color to blue.